# About Kolmogorov $0-1$ law

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, proof-explanation

Kolmogorov $0-1$ law states that if $A \in \mathcal{F}_{\infty}$, then $P(A)$ equal zero or one.

Here $\mathcal{F}_{\infty} = \bigcap_{n\geq 1} \mathcal{F}_n$ and $\mathcal{F}_n = \sigma(X_n, X_{n+1}, \ldots)$ is the sigma algebra generated by $X_i$ (random variables) with $i \geq n$ (hence "the future" wrt instant $n$). Those random variables are also real and independent.

We also call $Z$ a terminal (or tail) variable if it's measurable with respect to $\mathcal{F}_{\infty}$, or also if and only if $\forall n$ $Z$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$ measurable and I can write it as $Z = g_n(X_n, X_{n+1}, \ldots)$

**What I don't understand**

In the proof that I have, we start by calling $X_{\infty} = \mathbb{1}_A$ (the indicator function of the set $A$, or the event $A$).

- Why can we do that?

Then we proceed by wanting to prove that the variables $X_{\infty}, X_1, X_2, \ldots$ are independent, but we can reduce to a finite subfamily (like $X_{\infty}, X_1, \ldots X_k)$ and the conclusion follows from the fact that I can write

$$X_{\infty} = g_1(X_1, X_2, \ldots)$$

hence it's a terminal (or tail) random variable.

It then follows that $X_{\infty}$ is independent from itself.

- This I don't get: why is $X_{\infty}$ independent from itself? I don't get that conclusion from the previous reasoning.

Then we clearly end for $X_{\infty} = \mathbb{1}_A$ and hence an event $A$ is independent from itself iff $P(A) = P^2(A)$.

I don't get those two points though.

Thank you for your possible help.

Comment: This site has a really deep problem with those blokes that downvote at random...

Comment: On your first question: Are you asking why $1_A$ is a random variable?

Comment: I agree that this "problem" is currently at it's worst state. Many are just downvoting posts which are sufficiently detailed but maybe poorly posed(like this one). Another "problem" is that people are posting "show effort" comments to questions where such comments are irrelevant. That being said, the question posters are hardly reading/abiding by any rules. Many don't even bother to mark their solved queries as answers. Many don't even bother to interact with a comment that addresses an issue or confusing statement in the question body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You essentially want to show that the tail sigma algebra is independent of itself. Perhaps to bring in terminology for random variables(to make it more relatable) , the author is considering $\mathbf{1}_{A}$ instead of sets $A$.

The proof should go like this:

Consider any $k\geq 1$

$X_{\infty}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{k+1}$ measurable by definition as it is measurable wrt $\bigcap_{k\geq 1}\mathcal{F}_{k}$ which is a smaller sigma algebra contained in $\mathcal{F}_{k+1}$. (Note:An indicator $\mathbf{1}_{A}$ is measurable wrt $\mathcal{F}\iff A\in\mathcal{F}$)

But, $X_{1},...,X_{k}$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_{k+1}$ by definition.

Hence $\mathbf{1}_{A}$  is independent of $X_{1},...,X_{k}$.

But we chose $k$ arbitrarily. Hence $\mathbf{1}_{A}$ is independent of all the $X_{i}$'s . Hence $X_{\infty}$ is independent of $\sigma(X_{1},X_{2},...)=\mathcal{F}_{1}$

But $\mathbf{1}_{A}$ is measurable wrt $\mathcal{F}_{1}$ by definition as $\mathbf{1}_{A}$ is measurable wrt $\bigcap_{k\geq 1}\mathcal{F}_{k}$ and hence $A\in\mathcal{F}_{1}$. So, "$A$ is in a sigma algebra of which $A$ is independent off" . Thus, $A$ is independent of itself.

Hence $P(A\cap A)=P(A)^{2}\implies P(A)=0\,\text{or}\, 1$.

**Remark:(possibly unimportant)** One **SHOULD** feel somewhat cheated after reading any Zero-One law proof. It should seem that you are getting a very strong conclusion by just doing a bit of some silly logical jugglery which feels somewhat like a "[Saul Goodman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saul_Goodman)" type scam. If that feeling does not arise in one's head, then perhaps one should read again. The phenomenon should seem very weird on the first few readings. Only after you have seen many applications should the law make sense.

Comment: Thank you so much! And yes, I keep feeling scammed :D